# Why does Chrome not cache CSS/JS files with a self signed certificate?

Tags: google-chrome, security, caching

Testing a website locally with a self signed certificate.  The cache policy of my static resources is aggressive.  When inspecting network requests, images are loaded from cache but CSS/JS files are not.

What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently. I found this bug report on chromium.org:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=110649

It seems that Chromium browsers (Chrome, Brave, and others) do not cache script files, or rather do not cache them when requested in a particular way. I found that all the scripts I was requesting via jquery ajax calls using dataType: "script" (i.e. requested via xhr request) were never being cached. Safari and Firefox had no problem caching the files.

I did find that any scripts that were loaded inline in <script> tags were cached, so I am changing up my build code to add script tags to the html page for the scripts in question.

I'm guessing that this was deemed a security issue, in that chromium treats a self-signed certificate as a certificate error (even after accepting the cert), and thus the site is not to be trusted fully. I'm not clear as to why script assets embedded in the page are cached.